# Testing if Cell renders under specific Column in MUI DataGrid

Tags: material-ui, react-testing-library, mui-x-data-grid

I fully understand you shouldn't test third party libraries, but I'm wanting to test that a cell properly renders the correct data under a specific column using RTL and Jest, but am unsure of how to do this. One thought was to grab the column header and (under assumptions) thought I could do a within to search the entire column's rows, but it doesn't work. I haven't been able to find anything online about this.